# PHP GD Library imagecopyresized()

Tags: php, gd

I am getting the following error when trying to use GD Library's imagecopyresized method:

```
Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in....
```

Here is the line of code:

```
imagecopyresized($fullPath, $fullPath, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
```

$fullpath is equal to the following:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/imageCrop/img/fileName.png
```

Could anyone offer any help?

Answer (score -1):

Check the docs : http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

The resource is a binary data (a pointer) you will get by creatiing the image object

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

That's where you $*fullPath* goes.